# div delete after button click isn't working properly. Also not maintaining sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I append div one by one, it's working properly. but when I delete the first one or any from the previous one, it's not deleting properly. And if once again I want to append another div div-number is not maintaining sequence. Actually, I want to build a system where users can add products and also can delete the product during invoice generation. so please help me with how these kinds of stuff can be maintained. Also, I need to calculate the subtotal amount of individual products with individual div. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
               let divCount = 0;
               $(function() {
               $('#btnAddtoList').on('click', function(){
               divCount++;
               const div_title = divCount;
               var newDiv = $(
                `<div class=item-wrapper-${div_title}>` +
                  '<div class="container rounded bg-white mt-3 mb-3">' +
                    '<div class="row">' +
                      '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                        '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                          '<span><strong>পণ্যের বিবরণ #</strong></span>'+ div_title +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="row mt-1 text-center">' +
                          '<select class="product_option form-control" id="product">' +
                            '<option disabled selected> -- পণ্য পছন্দ করুন (পণ্যের নাম | বিক্রয় মূল্য | 
                               অ্যাভেলেবল আছে) -- 
                             </option>' +
                            '</select>' +
                         '</div>' +
                         '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                           '<label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">পণ্যের নাম</label>
                             <input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName">' +
                           '</div>' +
                         '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                           '<label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">বিক্রয় মূল্য</label>
                             <input type="number" class="form-control" id="sellPrice">' +
                         '</div>' +
                         '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                          '<label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">পণ্য মজুদ আছে </label> 
                           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="amount" ">' +
                         '</div>' +
                         '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                          '<label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">পরিমাণ</label>
                           <input type="number" class="form-control quantity_pro" id="quantity" ">' +
                         '</div>' +
                         `<div class="mt-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center">
                           <button class="btn btn-danger deleteItem" id=del-${div_title} 
                            type="button">মুছুন
                           </button>
                          </div>` +
                        '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>');
           $('.productDiv').append(newDiv);
           console.log(div_title);
           $(".item-wrapper-" + div_title).find(".product_option").select2({
             theme: "classic"
           });        
         firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            console.log(user);
                 if (user) {
                    var user_id = user.uid;
  
                     firebase.database().ref('Products/').child(user_id).once('value')
                     .then(function(snapshot){
                        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                              var product_name = childSnapshot.child("product_name").val();
                              var selling_price = childSnapshot.child("selling_price").val();
                              var amount = childSnapshot.child("product_quantity").val();
                              {#console.log(amount)#}
                              var total = product_name + " | " + selling_price + " | " + amount;
                              console.log(total);
                            $(".item-wrapper-" + div_title).find(".product_option").append('<option>' 
                            + total + '</option');
                              $(document).on("change", ".product_option", function () {
                                  const valArr = $(`.item-wrapper-${div_title} .product_option 
                       option:selected`).text().split(" | ");
                                  $(`div.item-wrapper-${div_title} #productName`).val(valArr[0]);
                                  $(`div.item-wrapper-${div_title} #sellPrice`).val(valArr[1]);
                                  $(`div.item-wrapper-${div_title} #amount`).val(valArr[2]);

                              });
                        });
                      })
                 }
                else{
                    window.location.href="{% url 'login' %}";
                }
            });
        });

        $("#subTotal").on('click', function (e) {
            var subTotalAmount = 0;
            for (var i = 1; i<=divCount; i++){
                var getProductName = $(`div.item-wrapper-${i} #productName`).val();
                var getSellingPrice = $(`div.item-wrapper-${i} #sellPrice`).val();
                var getAmount = $(`div.item-wrapper-${i} #amount`).val();
                var getQuantity = $(`div.item-wrapper-${i} #quantity`).val();
                subTotalAmount += getSellingPrice*getQuantity;
            }
            var SellingPriceFloat = parseFloat(getSellingPrice);

            var amountFloat = parseFloat(getAmount);
            console.log(amountFloat)

            var quantityFloat = parseFloat(getQuantity);
            console.log(quantityFloat);

            console.log(subTotalAmount)
            if (quantityFloat>amountFloat){
                alert("পর্যাপ্ত পরিমান পণ্য নেই ।");
            }
            else {
                // executes only once
                 var subDiv = $(
                 '<div class="item-wrapper">' +
                    '<div class="container rounded bg-white mt-3 mb-3">' +
                        '<div class="row">' +
                            '<div class="col-md-12">' +
                                '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                                  '<span class="col-md-12">সাব টোটালঃ</strong></span>'
                                   +subTotalAmount +
                                '</div>' +
                                    '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                                        '<label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">ডিসকাউন্ট(%) 
              </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="productName">' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                                        '<label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">ভ্যাট(%) 
                            </label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="sellPrice">' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '<div class="row mt-3">' +
                                        '<span class="col-md-12"><strong>মোটঃ</strong></span>'+
                                    '</div>' +
                         '<div class="mt-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center text- center"> 
                         <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">মোট</button></div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>');
                $('.subTotalDiv').html(subDiv);
            }
           });
           $(document).on("click", ".deleteItem", function() {
              $(this).closest(`.item-wrapper-${divCount}`).remove();
              divCount-=1;
           });

         });
      </script>
```

here is my html:

```
<div class="productDiv"></div>
<div class="mt-3 text-center">
  <button class="btn profile-button" style="color: white" type="button" 
  id="btnAddtoList">পণ্য যোগ করুন</button>
</div>
<div class="mt-3 text-center">
  <button class="btn profile-button" style="color: white" type="button" 
   id="subTotal" >সাব টোটাল</button>
  </div>
<div class="subTotalDiv"></div>
```

You can see that two div with the same div number:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's just a sample that two div number is the same. #2 and #2 showing instead of #1, #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many important issues in that code.

1. You are creating some dynamic elements having always the same `id`.
   An `id` must be unique. NEVER use an id in a loop or in an event handler that appends elements.
   Use a `class` instead.
2. When you have more than one or two lines of HTML concatenated in a string for some appending... Better use the [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method on a "template" hidden in the HTML.
   That makes your code more readable and maintainable, since the "template" to clone will appear as regular HTML in your code editor, so you can see typos right away.
   And the JS is then more concise.
3. The main advantage of using jQuery is its ease to "traverse" the DOM using easy and short methods.
   From a user action (like from a event triggered on a `<select>` element)... Use the wide set of method like [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/), [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/), [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/), [.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/), etc... to target the elements you want.

   **Reminder for your future coding**: Every time you have to add a number to a class to make it unique... Take it as a symptom of a bad coding. While an `id` must be unique to target ONE element, a class must be "generic" to target a set of similar elements.

   I **COMPLETELY removed** your "concept" of having the `divCount` an `div_title` variable in the below snippet.
   Your issue was NOT about how to correctly use it... But how to NOT use it. ;)
4. Function nesting.
   You used event delegation: `$(document).on("change", ".product_option", function () {...}`
   **Nice!** But that is inside the Firebase callback.
   And the Firebase request is inside the `btnAddtoList` click handler.

   So every times the user click on the `পণ্য যোগ করুন (Add products)` button, there is a request made to the database (most probably with the same result). And an additional delegated handler for all `.product_option` select in the page is setted.

   It does not looks too good right?
   And that was due to your (failed) attempt to use some "unique" `item-wrapper-*` classes...

---

So below is your code changed a lot. I did not dive into your Firebase request because I really don't know the structure of the response. I "assumed" a response with the `snapshot` array of objects. You may have something quite different.

Have a close look at the code and all the comments.

```js
console.clear();

$(function () {
  
  // Add a cloned div
  $("#btnAddtoList").on("click", function () {
    
    // Clone the template and toggle some classes
    let newDiv = $(".item-wrapper_template")
      .clone()
      .toggleClass("item-wrapper_template item-wrapper");
    
    // Append
    newDiv.find(".number").text($(".item-wrapper").length + 1);
    $(".productDiv").append(newDiv);
    
    // Instantiate Select2
    newDiv.find(".product_option").select2({
      theme: "classic"
    });
  });

  // Delete a cloned div
  $(document).on("click", ".deleteItem", function () {
    
    // Remove the whole wrapper div that holds the .deleteItem button
    $(this).closest(".item-wrapper").remove();
    
    // Update the numbers of the other items
    $(".item-wrapper").each(function (num) {
      $(this)
        .find(".number")
        .text(num + 1);
    });
  });

  // Calculate the sub total
  $("#subTotal").on("click", function (e) {
    
    // At each click event, start the calculation at zero
    let subTotalAmount = 0;
    
    // How many items now?
    let itemCount = $(".item-wrapper").length;

    // A flag to know if we break the loop
    let loopBreak = false;

    // Looping all the items
    for (let i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
      
      let getSellingPrice = parseFloat(
        $(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".sellPrice").val()
      );
      let getAmount = parseFloat(
        $(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".amount").val()
      );
      let getQuantity =
        parseFloat($(".item-wrapper").eq(i).find(".quantity").val()) || 0;

      // A condition check which may break the loop
      if (getQuantity > getAmount) {
        alert("পর্যাপ্ত পরিমান পণ্য নেই ।"); // There are not enough products.
        loopBreak = true;
        break;
      } else {
        subTotalAmount += getSellingPrice * getQuantity;
        console.log("subTotalAmount", subTotalAmount);
      }
    } // END for loop

    // If the loop was not broken
    if (!loopBreak) {
      $(".subTotalDiv").find(".subTotalAmount").text(subTotalAmount);
      $(".subTotalDiv").show();
    }
  });

  // Option change handler for ALL select element present on the page
  $(document).on("change", ".product_option", function () {
    const valArr = $(this).find("option:selected").text().split(" | ");
    $(this).closest(".item-wrapper").find(".productName").val(valArr[0]);
    $(this).closest(".item-wrapper").find(".sellPrice").val(valArr[1]);
    $(this).closest(".item-wrapper").find(".amount").val(valArr[2]);
  });
  
  
  // =====
  // Simulating the firebase database request

  // Let assume some data to make this example working
  let snapshot = [
    {
      product_name: "First Product",
      selling_price: 10.57,
      product_quantity: 42
    },
    {
      product_name: "Second Product",
      selling_price: 28.72,
      product_quantity: 17
    },
    {
      product_name: "Third Product",
      selling_price: 11.48,
      product_quantity: 8
    }
  ];

  /*
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      console.log(user);
      if (user) {
        var user_id = user.uid;

        firebase.database().ref('Products/').child(user_id).once('value')
        .then(function(snapshot){
        
          snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var product_name = childSnapshot.child("product_name").val();
            var selling_price = childSnapshot.child("selling_price").val();
            var amount = childSnapshot.child("product_quantity").val();
            
            {#console.log(amount)#}
            var total = product_name + " | " + selling_price + " | " + amount;
            console.log(total);
            
            $(".item-wrapper-" + div_title).find(".product_option").append('<option>'
            + total + '</option');

          });
          */
  
          // Here, I am simulating the option appending from the simulated snapshot array above
          // Notice I append it to the template!
          snapshot.forEach(function (item, index) {
            
            // Format the text of the option
            let optionText =
              item.product_name +
              " | " +
              item.selling_price +
              " | " +
              item.product_quantity;
            
            // Create the option and append
            let option = $("<option>").text(optionText);
            $(".item-wrapper_template").find(".product_option").append(option);
          });
  
          /*
        })
      }
      else{
        window.location.href="{% url 'login' %}";
      }
    });
    */
});
```

```css
.item-wrapper_template{
  display: none;
}
.subTotalDiv{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<div class="productDiv"></div>

<!-- That is a TEMPLATE -->
<div class=item-wrapper_template>
  <div class="container rounded bg-white mt-3 mb-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <span><strong>পণ্যের বিবরণ (Product Description) #</strong></span><span class="number">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-1 text-center">
          <select class="product_option form-control">
            <option disabled selected> -- পণ্য পছন্দ করুন (পণ্যের নাম | বিক্রয় মূল্য | অ্যাভেলেবল আছে) -- </option>
            <option disabled> -- Choose Product (Product Name | Sale Price | Available) -- </option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">পণ্যের নাম (Product name)</label> <input type="text" class="form-control productName">
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">বিক্রয় মূল্য (Sale price)</label> <input type="number" class="form-control sellPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">পণ্য মজুদ আছে (There are stockpiles of products)</label> <input type="text" class="form-control amount">
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">পরিমাণ (Amount)</label> <input type="number" class="form-control quantity_pro quantity">
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center"> <button class="btn btn-danger deleteItem" type="button">মুছুন (Delete)</button> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- That is your "normal" HTML -->
<div class="mt-3 text-center">
  <button id="btnAddtoList" class="btn profile-button" type="button">পণ্য যোগ করুন (Add products)</button>
</div>
<div class="mt-3 text-center">
  <button id="subTotal" class="btn profile-button" type="button">সাব টোটাল (Sub Total)</button>
</div>

<!-- That is hidden by CSS but shown by JS -->
<div class="subTotalDiv">
  <div class="container rounded bg-white mt-3 mb-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <span class="col-md-12">সাব টোটালঃ (Sub Total:)</strong></span><span class="subTotalAmount">0</span>
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">ডিসকাউন্ট(%) (Discount (%))</label><input type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <label class="labels" style="font-size: 16px">ভ্যাট(%) (VAT (%))</label><input type="text" class="form-control sellPrice">
        </div>
        <div class="row mt-3">
          <span class="col-md-12"><strong>মোটঃ (Total:)</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-3 d-flex flex-column align-items-center text- center"> <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">মোট (Total)</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/ZEpxrmL?editors=1111)